# Beautifyrc SCSS adding new white line after closing curly brace

Tags: css, sass, stylesheet

Can anyone help me out on how to add a new white space after each CSS-block (after the closing curly brace) by adjusting the settings for the beautifyrc-file?

the SCSS-problem:

```
.return-btn {
 background-color: #ACE514 !important;
 border: 0;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #1F8619 !important;
 border-radius: 0;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}
.return-btn:hover {
 background-color: #ACE514 !important;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #1F8619 !important;
}
```

I want a new white space after the closing bracket of ".return-btn" when I beautify my .scss.

My current settings in the default.jsbeautifyrc:

```
{
"js": {
    "eol": "\n",
    "preserve_newlines": true,
    "max_preserve_newlines": 10,
    "space_after_anon_function": true,
    "brace_style": "collapse",
    "keep_array_indentation": true,
    "keep_function_indentation": false,
    "space_before_conditional": true,
    "break_chained_methods": false,
    "eval_code": false,
    "unescape_strings": false,
    "wrap_line_length": 0,
    "wrap_attributes": "auto",
    "end_with_newline": true,
    "comma_first": false
},
"css": {
    "allowed_file_extensions": ["css", "scss", "sass", "less"],
    "eol": "\\n",
    "end_with_newline": true,
    "selector_separator_newline": true,
    "newline_between_rules": true,
    "smartIndent": false,
    "indent_char": " ",
    "indent_size": 2,
    "selector_separator": " "
},
"html": {
    "eol": "\n",
    "end_with_newline": true,
    "preserve_newlines": true,
    "max_preserve_newlines": 10,
    "indent_inner_html": false,
    "brace_style": "collapse",
    "indent_scripts": "normal",
    "wrap_line_length": 0,
    "wrap_attributes": "auto"
}
}
```

When i format the outputted css-file itself, a newline is added after each closing curly brace but not in the scss-file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this feature isn't available now and already requested, see [newline_between_rules support for Sass (enhancement)](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/657) for more info.